# Publish motion chart: set initial state

Tags: google-visualization

After creating a motion chart in a spreadsheet and selecting 'Publish', I get the following code, which pasted into an HTML page on my server produces a working chart (I removed my spreadsheet URL):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/static/modules/gviz/1.0/chart.js"> {"dataSourceUrl":"//docs.google.com/spreadsheet/tq?key=[mysheet]&transpose=0&headers=1&range=A1%3AC57&gid=0&pub=1","options":{"showChartButtons":true,"vAxes":[{"title":"Left vertical axis title","useFormatFromData":true,"minValue":null,"viewWindow":{"min":null,"max":null},"maxValue":null},{"useFormatFromData":true,"minValue":null,"viewWindow":{"min":null,"max":null},"maxValue":null}],"titleTextStyle":{"fontSize":16},"title":"Chart title","booleanRole":"certainty","height":643,"animation":{"duration":500},"width":1468,"showSidePanel":true,"hAxis":{"title":"Horizontal axis title","useFormatFromData":true,"minValue":null,"viewWindow":{"min":null,"max":null},"maxValue":null}},"state":{},"view":{},"isDefaultVisualization":true,"chartType":"MotionChart","chartName":"Chart 1"} </script>
```

However the chart does not maintain any state changes I have made in the chart's display: Color, Size, Lin/Log, etc.

I can acquire the current state settings string via the advanced dialog:

```
{"yLambda":0,"xZoomedDataMax":381835,"colorOption":"_UNIQUE_COLOR","xZoomedIn":false,"showTrails":false,"yZoomedIn":false,"playDuration":15000,"nonSelectedAlpha":0.4,"xLambda":0,"yAxisOption":"2","yZoomedDataMax":381835,"yZoomedDataMin":6213,"iconType":"BUBBLE","time":"2000","orderedByX":false,"iconKeySettings":[{"key":{"dim0":"Metric1"}},{"key":{"dim0":"Metric2"}},{"key":{"dim0":"Metric3"}},{"key":{"dim0":"Metric4"}}],"dimensions":{"iconDimensions":["dim0"]},"orderedByY":false,"duration":{"multiplier":1,"timeUnit":"Y"},"sizeOption":"2","uniColorForNonSelected":false,"xAxisOption":"2","xZoomedDataMin":6213}
```

But placing them in the "state":{} parameter in my HTML file has no effect. I've tried placing the state string in various other locations, again without effect. Where do I put the state string to display my desired initial state?

Answer (score 1):

You add them to the "state" option as a string, not an object:

```
state: '{"yLambda":0,"xZoomedDataMax":381835,"colorOption":"_UNIQUE_COLOR","xZoomedIn":false,"showTrails":false,"yZoomedIn":false,"playDuration":15000,"nonSelectedAlpha":0.4,"xLambda":0,"yAxisOption":"2","yZoomedDataMax":381835,"yZoomedDataMin":6213,"iconType":"BUBBLE","time":"2000","orderedByX":false,"iconKeySettings":[{"key":{"dim0":"Metric1"}},{"key":{"dim0":"Metric2"}},{"key":{"dim0":"Metric3"}},{"key":{"dim0":"Metric4"}}],"dimensions":{"iconDimensions":["dim0"]},"orderedByY":false,"duration":{"multiplier":1,"timeUnit":"Y"},"sizeOption":"2","uniColorForNonSelected":false,"xAxisOption":"2","xZoomedDataMin":6213}'
```

And that is specifically the state *option* (that is, a parameter of `options`), not the state *parameter*, as the MotionCharts are a legacy visualization that predates the modern structure.  It gets entered like this:

```
options: {/* list of options */, state: 'state string'}
```

not like this:

```
options: {/* list of options */}, state: 'state string'
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you are saying. However I still cannot get it to work. I've modified by adding the bolded portion as shown; for simplicity the only state option I'm trying to change is "showTrails:false" at the moment. '"options":{**"state":'"showTrails":false'**,"showChartButtons":true,...'

Comment: Okay, adding brackets seems to do the trick! Final working syntax is: '"options":{**"state":'{"showTrails":false}'**,"showChartButtons":true,...'